# Making Kafka consumers consume existing messages before subscription

Tags: apache-kafka

Having Publisher and N Consumers, if consumers use `auto.offset.reset=latest` then they miss all the messages that were published to a topic before they subscribed to it ... It is a known fact that Consumer with `auto.offset.reset=latest`doesn't replay messages that existed in the topic before it subscribed...

So I would need either :

1. Make publisher wait until all subscribers start consuming messages and then start publishing. Dunno how to do that without leveraging Zookeeper for instance. Does Kafka provide means to do that ?
2. Another way would be having `auto.offset.reset=latest` Consumers and make them explicitly consume all existing messages before in case they are about to subscribe to a topic with existing messages...

What is the best practice for this case?

I guess that consumer must check topic for existing messages, consume them if there are any and then initiate `auto.offset.reset=latest` consumption. That sounds like the best way to me ...

Comment: Is there any harm with using `auto.offset.reset=earliest` ?

Comment: If you use earliest, you'd need to memoize or persist last offset in order to know where you stopped last time, right? I just realized that both options are totally wrong and that the only way to get the is memoizing the last offset ...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You just need to track offsets every time. Would you mind to tell about your use-case like where exactly you are using Kafka, and which processing engine you are using like spark or storm? also whether it is batch processing or streaming?

Answer (score 1):

If a high level consumer gets started, it does the following:

1. look for committed offsets for its consumer group

   a. if valid offsets are found, resume from there

   b. if no valid offsets are found, set offsets according to `auto.offset.reset`

Thus, `auto.offset.reset` only triggers, if no valid offset was committed. This behavior is intended and necessary to provide at-least-once processing guarantees in case of failure.

Thus, is you want to read a topic from its beginning, you can either use a new consumer `group.id` and set `auto.offset.reset = earliest` or you explicitly modify the offsets on startup using `seekToBeginning()` before you start your `poll()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

We do the option (1) using a service discovery feature provided by Eureka (any other service discovery app would do the job) + aliasing. Basically a publisher does not register itself (and start processing requests nor publish notifications) until at least one subscriber is available.